# Flex 4 vs. ExtJS 4 vs other JS frameworks

Tags: extjs, flex4, javascript-framework

I've multiple web projects ahead of me and choosing the right client technology for RIA development is going to be essential for each. I'm wondering how people evaluate which technologies to use in their projects. Some specific projects I'm facing are;

1. Back-office features for an e-commerce app
2. Web store for selling some turnkey services
3. A social web community for book writers where they share their works and get rated like in SO.

I know all technologies have their pros and cons, just want to know some of the experiences experts have had out there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This varies based on longevity of your application.  The cost of putting out your first release is dwarfed by maintenance cost over time/releases.   For short term apps, it almost doesn't matter what you use.  But if you are an ISV (independent software vendor) you will want to choose a technology that matches your architecture and application life-cycle.

I recently went through the exercise of choosing a new UI architecture for an exist business application.   Based on my requirements for a solid architectural approach, scalable infrastructure, multi-release and lifecycle time horizon of greater than 5 years (realistically 10+ years), I chose Adobe Flex.

Now 6 releases into it, spanning upgrades from Flex2, 3, 4, Flex has proven to be an excellent choice.   It scores A+ in programmer productivity, maintainability, opensource community and developer support.  And aside from Flash not running on the iPad, it has unparalleled cross platform support and consistent user experience across browsers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I've really been leaning towards Flex myself as I love it as a framework. The only thing stopping me is the iPad/iPhone issue along with no google indexing. Those two are the only reasons I was looking at ExtJS 4.

Comment: Well, you need to lay out your requirements and make a decision on that.  If this is an application vs a website I don't understand the google indexing issue.  Flash/flex websites have mechanism for SO.  If you are developing for tablet's you should think about developing an App vs just a webpage; the user experience requirements are very different.  Adobe Air works on IOS.  It sounds like you've already made your decision to use EXT-JS and are looking for validation.

Comment: Actually I have not decided yet, I'm over the fence due to multiple reasons. You got me curious though, how do you make google index your website content if it's flash based? I also agree that targeting tablets is an entirely different issue and may not be relevant to many projects.

Comment: If this is a major concern, you should do some investigation.  a google search returned 8M results on the topic.  Here is a link from adobe's site:http://www.adobe.com/devnet/seo.html.  it sounds like your application is more of a website than an RIA application.   if you would like to see an RIA app, you can view my demo app  http://demo.layerzngn.com:8080/cpClient   user/pass is demo/cplane or admin/admin